# Keeping the context of a function

Tags: matlab, function

I'd like to know whether it was possible to do this with Matlab or not.

I have a script that create and initialize a lot of variable. In my main program I call this script to do all the initialization then I go on manipulating the data.

I want to improve that script and make it function-like : I'd like to have different version of my program that will use the slightly different initialized values.

However I can't do that because I can't call a script with arguments and if I create a function with that script I won't recover the context of the function (and I don't want to modify the script that much so I can return things).

So I'm kinda stuck here. Does anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest a few options:

1. Save the desired variable to a mat file with `save`. In the script file, you can then `load,` and if desired delete the file.
2. Try to save same of the variables as global (to do that, declare `global` in front of the desired variables in both the function call, and the scripts):

To do the last option:

```
global Vari
Vari = sum (....);
```